# window.alert() overwrite click event for another button. any easy fix - JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclicklistener

I'm fairly new to JS and I'm messing around with events, I have a window.alert to say that the page has loaded, and a click event that loads a img when I press a button (note: I am pretty sure this button is ided properly, so the click should only work for that particular button). however, the ok button built into the window.alrt is triggering the click event. this is probably an easy fix hover like I said I'm new to js so any help would be grate.
Thanks.

here is my code
JS:
const notbutton = window.alert("Page is loaded");

```
function loaded()
{
    notbutton;
}

window.addEventListener("load", loaded());

document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", show1());

function show1()
{
    document.querySelector("#img1").style.display = "flex";
}
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";

#img1 {
    display: none;
}
#img2 {
    display: none;
}
#img3 {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stlyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p id="test"></p>
    <img id="img1" src="thestrip1.gif" />

    <button id="button1">Click Me!</button>
    
    <img id="img2" src="thestrip2.gif" />
    <img id="img3" src="thestrip3.gif" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this you're not adding `show1` as the click handler, you're *invoking* `show1` and setting its return value as the click handler.

```js
addEventListener("click", show1()); // don't do this
```

`show1()` is being called immediately when this code runs. The button in the alert isn't triggering this, it's just happening (or becomes apparent) after you dismiss the alert.

To fix it pass the function itself (without the `()`) instead of calling it:

```js
addEventListener("click", show1);
```